# Fill array with permutations (a-z) using bash

Tags: arrays, bash

I am looking to populate an array using the `{a..z}`. The end result is every letter from `a-z` stored in an array that can be used for referencing later.

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#proof of concept
#echo {a..z}
#a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

#attempt 1
CHARSET=({a..z})
printf "${CHARSET[@]}"
#result: a

#attempt 2
CHARSET=({a..z})
for i in CHARSET ; do
    echo "$1"
done
exit
#result a
```

Ultimately I am trying to test every permutation of `a-z` up to 4 characters long without making an intermediate file to read from e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {a..z}; do
for j in {a..z}; do
for k in {a..z}; do
for l in {a..z}; do
echo $i >>test.txt #1 letter
echo $i$j >>test.txt #2 letters
echo $i$j$k >>test.txt #3 letters
echo $i$j$k$l >>test.txt #4 letters
done;done;done;done
```

`test.txt`

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
...........
z
zz
zzz
zzzz
```

I was hoping to be able to store `a-z` in an array then use that array each time to increase the letter count up to four. Or is there a much simpler way to succeed here? (Without creating the intermediate file as given in the example above)

Comment: `CHARSET=({a..z})` works fine. Incorrect use of `printf`. See `help printf`.

Comment: `printf "%s\n" "${CHARSET[@]}"` (or for one-letter per-line, remove the quotes from `${CHARSET[@]}`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks for the quick fix to my code above :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append multiple brace expansions to combinatorially combine them:

```
for word in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}
do
  echo "$word"
done
```

Comment: @Ben: or alternatively: `printf "%s\n" {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}`

Comment: @Cyrus thanks Cyrus for the info, I'm still learning and the man/help pages sometimes get a bit too in depth for me to really understand. Especially with no working examples given :(

Comment: @Ben: I assume that's gonna help: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf